# Find string with single quote

Tags: php, regex, string

I have an array of strings . I need all the strings which do not contain any special character. Only a to z is allowed. Is there any method using regex or is there any string function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex `^[a-zA-Z]*$` which matches strings that only contain A to Z and a to z. (It will also match an empty string).

Explanation:

- `^` is an anchor that anchors the regex at the start of the string (So the regex starts matching from the start of the string)
- `[a-zA-Z]` is a character class that contains the characters we want to match
- `*` indicates that it should be matched zero or more times (use + for one or more times)
- `$` is an anchor for the end of the string, so the regex has to stop matching at the end of the string or it won't be a match.

You use preg_match to check a single string to see if it matches a pattern (preg_match returns 0 if there is no match, so we just check there is a match):

```
if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $subject) !== 0 ){
    //match
```

Hence you can then iterate over the array of strings, and create a new array of those that match the pattern

Comment: preg_match returns 1 or 0 so i think !== false is not working. Type is different. !== 0 is working fine

Comment: @Nisnath Good catch. PHPs return values are so inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = "your_array";
$output_array = array();
foreach ($array as $elem) {
    if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$/', $elem)) {
        $output_array[] = $elem;
    }
}
```

in output_array will be your data